# SwiftUI: Path() returning nil in ios13 beta 5

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

I'm playing around with SwiftUI in IOS13 beta. After updating my system to beta5 (Catalyst, Xcode, IOS), I experienced a problem with my SwiftUI-shapes that worked well in beta4..

The `Path()` constructor in beta5 is constantly returning nil, so my code is crashing when trying to render a SwiftUI shape/path..

While trying to track down the issue I set up a very basic new project with a simple ContentView struct. This project is showing the same behaviour..

So currently I don't believe it's an issue within my project-environment but within the framework..

I also tried to have the path in a struct conforming to the shape-protocol (uncommented code below), but the result is the same: the constructor `Path()` in `func path(...)` is also returning nil.

```
    import SwiftUI

    //struct CheckShape : Shape {
    //    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    //        
    //        var path = Path()
    //        
    //        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    //        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    //        
    //        return path
    //    }
    //    
    //    
    //}

    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Path { p in
                    let p1 = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
                    let p2 = CGPoint(x: geo.size.width, y: geo.size.height)
                    p.move(to: p1)
                    p.addLine(to: p2)
                }
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the code in the simulator (or on the device) and break in the Path-closure, I see that p is nil and as a consequence, the code breaks with a 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)'

Has anybody seen the same behavior and can suggest a solution/workaround?